# Can I reuse the QSvgRenderer when I modify the QByteAray contents?

Tags: qt, svg, qgraphicsitem

I have a `QGraphicsSvgItem` subclass that contains an svg that I can change based on user actions.

I can have multiple items of that type - they get created by loading an svg and setting a new svg renderer on them. I am not sure if this is the most effective way - it is how I saw it done in examples.

I store the svg, after loading, in a `QByteArray` - for fast changes I do string replace on things hat can change. (I have tried to use xml but conversions to `QByteAray` are too slow).

So... on load item, I do:

```
inFile >> m_svgContents;   // which is QByteArray
setSharedRenderer(new QSvgRenderer(m_svgContents));
```

Then on any change, `m_svgContents` gets modified, and I have to do

```
m_svgContents.replace(oldInfo, newInfo);
delete renderer();
setSharedRenderer(new QSvgRenderer(m_svgContents));
```

I just added `delete renderer();` because I ran valgrind and it showed a memory leak.

It seems very heavy weight to create a new renderer each time...
Is it possible to reuse the renderer ?
The "shared renderer" would suggest that I could share it between multiple items - which is probably not useful to me because each item can have a diferent svg content - and my understanding is that each renderer is per a different svg file...

But maybe it is possible to reuse, instead of deleting and creating a new renderer, when I change the svg contents ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And how about `QSvgRenderer::load()` ? It should replace current SVG content with the new one.

Comment: Thanks I can use this. It seems not to cause an update - so I must call it myself - and I get weird results if I use it on first load... (if `renderer()` I tried to `load` instead of `new` and got a giant svg)